# Can I make a function table regardless of parameter signature?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I want to call all types of functions from a single table.
(Consider returns types are all void)

To illustrate what I am talking about, here is some code that obviously does not work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <functional>

void foo(int x){std::cout<<x;}
void bar(){std::cout<<"bar";}


std::map<std::string, std::function<void()>> map = 
{
    {"foo", foo},
    {"bar", bar}
};

int main()
{
    map["foo"](2);
    map["bar"]();
}
```

I am not opposed to a C style solution.

Comment: like [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/74fd8557676d6d39) ?

Comment: How will you CALL these functions? Surely at that time you will know the parameters. In which case, why not have a separate map for each type of function signature. You can use a templated class, where the function type is the template parameter, which contains a static map.

Comment: @NeilKirk I am considering that too. I am writing an ad hoc interpreter for a simple language. The values will come from the user.

Comment: So you have a string of text like `"foo(2)"`. How do you plan to get from that to a line of code that reads `map["foo"](2);`? Think through this part first.

Comment: If you're writing an interpreter, perhaps the appropriate signature for a dynamically typed language is more like function<boost::any(vector<boost::any>)>, or likely function<boost::variant<...>(vector<boost::variant<...>>); it will be very difficult to call your functions if they have different signatures unless you descend into the hell of C-style variadics.

Comment: @StefanAtev How about wrapper functions taking vector<string> and letting these wrappers do some interpreting and calling the original functions. That seems easier to manage in my opinion.

Comment: Did you see the facebook talk at cppcon2014? I highly recommend it to you. You will change your design :D

Comment: @manasij7479 If the wrapper functions take vector<string>, then each one of them has to be responsible for parsing arguments; ideally, yopu'd have a vector<boost::any> parse_args(vector<string>) somewhere else in the code and not require every wrapper function to invoke that - that's a recipe for forgetting to do something and for duplicated code. Also, variant<> is probably better. All of this concerns writing a _simple_ interpreter that will not try to JIT or convert to bytecode first.

Answer (score 1):

You could declare your pointer an old style C function pointer to 
a variadic function like:

```
 foo(...);
 bar(...);

 std::map<void(*)(...)> map = 
 {
    {"foo", foo},
    {"bar", bar}
 };
```

but then foo and bar have to follow the variadic calling convention with va_args, va_start
 etc and you may only pull C PODs from the list. Don't know if its worth the hassle. The calling method still somehow has to know which number of args to pass.

Looks a bit as if you may rethink your design.

If for example this is supposed to be a command table for a kind of CLI it might be better to pass an `std::vector<std::string>` to each potential command and make it figure out if the vector has the correct size() for its purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If you totally forsake the type system, you can use `boost::any` as long as you get all the types exactly right everywhere. Right now only works with explicitly making everything a std::function but I'm sure there's a workaround for that too (update added an overload for free functions):

```
class Functions
{
public:
    template <typename... T>
    void add_function(const std::string& name, void (*f)(T...))
    {   
        fs[name] = std::function<void(T...)>{f};
    }   


    template <typename... T>
    void add_function(const std::string& name, std::function<void(T...)> f)
    {   
        fs[name] = f;
    }   

    template <typename... T>
    void call(const std::string& name, T... args)
    {   
        auto it = fs.find(name);
        if (it != fs.end()) {
            auto f = boost::any_cast<std::function<void(T...)>>(&it->second);
            if (f) {
                (*f)(args...);
            }   
            else {
                std::cout << "invalid args for " << name << std::endl;
            }
        }   
        else {
            std::cout << "not found: " << name << std::endl;
        }   
    }   

private:
    std::map<std::string, boost::any> fs; 
};

void baz() {
    std::cout << "baz" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::function<void()> foo = []{ std::cout << "foo" << std::endl; };
    std::function<void(int)> bar = [](int i){ std::cout << "bar(" << i << ")" << std::endl;     
};

    Functions f;
    f.add_function("foo", foo );
    f.add_function("bar", bar);
    f.add_function("baz", baz);

    f.call("foo");
    f.call("bar", 42);
    f.call("baz");
}
```

Functional, yes. Good idea? Note also that `f.call("bar", 42u)` will fail because you have to get every type *exactly* right.

Answer (score 0):

I changed a bit your approach, and be aware it's just an example, I'm pretty sure it won't compile like this, but it will give you an idea of what I had in mind.
You can register your functions in an additional struct, and then call the appropriate one, forwarding the parameters.

```
struct Funcs
{
    std::function<void(int)> _f1;
    std::function<void()>    _f2;

    template<typename args...>
    void call(std::string&& f_name, args...)
    {
        if(f_name == "foo")
          _f1(std::forward(args)...)
        if(f_name == "bar")
          _f2(std::forward(args)...)
    }
}


int main()
{
    Funcs f;
    f.call("foo", 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to store any function, and can always figure out how to call it correctly, you can expand on Oncaphillis' approach and just go ahead and cast the function pointers:

```
void foo(int);
float bar(double, struct baz);

std::map<void(*)()> map = {
    {"foo", (void(*)())foo},
    {"bar", (void(*)())bar}
};
```

Then you can cast them back when you use them:

```
//code to make sure that map["foo"] is of type `void(*)(int)`
(*(void(*)(int))map["foo"])(42);

//code to make sure that map["bar"] is of type `float(*)(double, struct baz)`
float result = (*(float(*)(double, struct baz))map["foo"])(3.14159, (struct baz){ /*whatever*/});
```

As you see, it is no problem to call any type of function that way, without restricting to variadic ones. However, this approach is very error prone as you completely do away with the safety provided by the type system, and your casts must be 100% correct. Weird stuff may happen if you don't. That's the same problem as with using `boost::any`.